# R programming, excel file calculations and modification through R

Tags: r

[Here is the screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvNGm.png)

I am trying to do the sum of each column of my excel file sales.csv
So I was trying to execute the below code, but the sum which I am getting is zero for all the column. Below is my code:

```
sales <- read.csv("Dress Sales.csv")
names(sales)
sales[,-c(25:36)]->sales
sales
sales = as.data.frame(lapply(sales, as.numeric))

#NAs to be imputed by row mean
sales_matrix = as.matrix(sales)

rowMean = apply(sales_matrix[,-1],1,mean,na.rm=T)

i=1
for(i in 1:nrow(sales_matrix))
{
  if(sum(is.na(sales_matrix[i,]))>0)
    sales_matrix[i, is.na(sales_matrix[i,])] = rowMean[i]
}

colSums(is.na(sales_matrix))
```

Comment: No need for a screenshot, put all your data as text in the question itself.

Comment: Your are printing the value of colSums of `is.na(sales_matrix)`, is it possible you have no NA values?

Comment: no i have na values so i have to remove that also

Comment: If you remove the NA values before `colSums(is.na(sales_matrix))` you will get zero. Since that line of code basically is summing the number of `is.na=T` values. Maybe you just want `colSums(sales_matrix)`

Answer (score 0):

With `colSums(is.na(sales_matrix))` you are simply counting the number of NA values in a given column. I am not sure if that is what you are after.

Instead if you want an actual sum of the columns of `sales_matrix` use:
`colSums(sales_matrix,na.rm=T)`